# Cosa significa "tornito" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *L'amica geniale* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> La ricchezza, incarnandosi in Stefano, stava prendendo le sembianze di un giovane uomo col camice unto, stava mettendo lineamenti, odore, voce, esprimeva simpatia e bontà, era un maschio che conoscevamo da sempre, il figlio grande di don Achille. 
>          Mi agitai. 
>         «Comunque ti voleva pungere la lingua» dissi. 
>         «Era un ragazzino» lei replicò commossa, zuccherosa come non l’avevo mai sentita, tanto che solo in quel momento mi accorsi che s’era spinta di fatto ben più avanti di quanto mi avesse detto a parole. 
>         Nei giorni seguenti tutto diventò sempre più chiaro. Vidi come parlava a Stefano e come lui sembrava **tornito** dalla sua voce. Mi adattai al patto che stavano stringendo, non volevo essere tagliata fuori. E complottammo per ore – noi due, noi tre – per fare in modo che mutassero in fretta le persone, i sentimenti, la disposizione delle cose.

Non capisco cosa vuol dire "tornito" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato "tornire" e "tornito" in alcuni dizionari e ho trovato che può significare  lavorato al tornio, ben modellato, di forme tonde e armoniose..., ma tutte queste accezioni non sembrano avere senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: sapreste spiegarmi qual è il senso di "tornito" nel brano precedente?

Comment: Secondo me è un granchio preso dall'autrice. Puoi aggiungere un po' di contesto?

Comment: Sembra anche a me un granchio o semplice refuso. “Intontito”??

Comment: @egreg: Ho messo un brano un po' più lungo.

Comment: Forse, ma è un'ipotesi azzardata, la voce dell'interlocutrice di Stefano lo “tornisce” nel senso che lo plasma, lo manipola?

Comment: Anche secondo me nel contesto l'accezione giusta è plasmare. Inoltre dopo si parla del tentativo di mutare le persone. Tornire può avere un significato più ampio. per citare  Hofmannsthal: Una piuma può tornire una pietra se la muove la mano dell'amore.

Comment: Grazie, @WalterVilla, a parte che stai però citando il traduttore (chi è?) di Hofmannsthal.  :-)

Comment: Be' le parole sono sue... almeno in tedesco... è uno scrittore austriaco. Il traduttore non saprei.

Comment: @DaG dopo un piccola ricerca: Gabriella Bemporad

Comment: @WalterVilla: Appunto, Hofmannsthal scriveva in tedesco, e quindi la scelta della parola “tornire” rispetto a qualsiasi altra formulazione è di chi ha tradotto in italiano. Grazie per aver trovato il nome!

Comment: @DaG: "Plasmare" nel senso di "modellare il modo di essere di una persona"? Può darsi. A proposito, l'interlocutrice di Stefano è Lila, l'amica della narratrice, protagonista del romanzo.

Comment: Sono sempre più del parere che l'autrice sia stata vittima di un'assonanza.

Comment: Dal contesto riportato lo interpreto come *ammaliato*

Comment: @Chamaeleon Benvenuto! Una risposta dovrebbe essere più motivata, perciò ho convertito la tua in un commento. In effetti sembri condividere la mia opinione che sia un *qui pro quo*, vedi i miei commenti sopra.

Comment: Sono d'accordo con @DaG. Tornito nel senso di lavorato, quindi completamente plagiato dalle sue parole.

Comment: @egreg: Sono ogni volta più convinta che questo verbo sia usato nel passaggio per descrivere lo stato psicologico della narratrice. Da ragazzine, Lila e Lenù hanno sempre considerato Stefano come un personaggio antipatico, soprattutto perché figlio di don Achille (che rappresenta per le bambine una specie di orco delle favole), ma anche perché aveva insultato e minacciato Lila con pungerle la lingua quando a scuola questa si era mostrata più brava del fratello di Stefano, Alfonso. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Adesso a Lenù sembra che le parole di Lila stiano tornendo Stefano nel senso che stanno cambiando il concetto che lei ha di Stefano.

Comment: @FrancaFacchetti: Il tuo post è più un commento che una risposta, per questa ragione è stato convertito in un commento.

Answer (score 1):

Non ho letto l'opera in questione, quindi la mia conoscenza del contesto è limitata, <s>ma da quel che leggo nell'estratto, la ricchezza si incarna in Stefano e gli parla, stringendo con lui un patto di qualche sorta, al quale la voce narrante aderisce con riluttanza.</s>

EDIT: a stringere il patto con Stefano è Raffaella, l'amica dell'io narrante. Il senso generale della risposta, però, non cambia.

È probabile che l'interpretazione da dare sia più letterale di quanto non sembri: Raffaella si rivolge a Stefano, egli accetta le sue parole e ne viene condizionato; forse il narratore avverte un cambiamento in Stefano riconducibile proprio alle parole che l'amica gli rivolge, come se questa lo stesse plasmando a mo'di un artigiano che tornisce il suo pezzo.

Quindi probabilmente si tratta di un significato simile a quello del verbo plagiare, se usato nello stesso contesto e avulso della sua sfumatura negativa, ovvero

> esercitare un particolare ascendente intellettuale e morale su un individuo

([Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/plagiare_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/))

Comment: La ricchezza si è incarnata in Stefano; chi parla a Stefano è l'amica dell'io narrante.

Comment: @egreg Grazie dell'info, correggo. Ma allora la prima metà dell'estratto a che serviva? :)

Comment: Raffaella ed Elena ("l'io narrante") sognavano da ragazzine col divenire ricche. Adesso sono adolescenti e, per Raffaella, questa ricchezza sognata da piccola, si sta incarnando nel personaggio di Stefano (salumiere che è diventato ricco col suo negozio).

Comment: Come ho detto nel mio commento alla domanda, non penso che ci sia nessun cambiamento in Stefano, ma piuttosto nella mente della narratrice, nel modo in cui questa considera Stefano.

Answer (score -1):

Treccani dice:

> tornire v. tr. [der. di tornio] (io tornisco, tu tornisci, ecc.). – 1.Lavorare al tornio, arrotondare e levigare con la lavorazione al tornio: t. un pezzo metallico; t. il legno, l’avorio.2. fig. Elaborare, rifinire, condurre a perfezione formale: t. una frase, un periodo, un verso, e anche una pagina,un sonetto, un madrigale. ◆ Part. pass. tornito, anche come agg.: pezzi meccanici, elementi di legno torniti; un vaso di ceramica tornito, ben tornito;levò dalla sporta una scatola d’un legno ordinario, ma tornita e lustrata con una certa finitezza cappuccinesca(Manzoni); più spesso in senso estens. e fig.: braccia, gambe ben tornite, di rotondità perfetta e di forme molto armoniche, così da sembrare lavorate al tornio: la gamba t. risaliva a un seno procace e molle (Claudio Magris); versi, periodi perfettamente torniti, rifiniti con eleganza.

[link](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tornire/)

In questo caso, invece credo significhi qualcosa del tipo**riempito**, **annebbiato** e forse era **concentrato e sentiva solo la sua voce**.

In ogni caso io direi:

> E rimase avvolto dalla sua voce.

Credo che la parola *avvolto* sia migliore.

> avvolgere
>   avvòlgere (letter. avvòlvere) v. tr. [dal lat. advolvĕre, rifatto su volgere] (coniug. come volgere). – 1. a. Girare una o più volte una cosa intorno a un’altra o su sé stessa: a. il filo sul rocchetto; a. un nastro intorno al cappello; si avvolse la sciarpa al collo;Erano i capei d’oro a l’aura sparsi Che ’n mille dolci nodi gli avolgea(Petrarca). b. Con altra costruzione, circondare un oggetto con un altro, involtare: avvolgersi il capo con un turbante; a. una scatola in carta velina; fig.: a. in una rete d’inganni (non com.a. uno, raggirarlo). Talora è soggetto l’involucro stesso: tolse la stagnola che avvolgeva la cioccolata; una benda gli avvolgeva il braccio ferito; anche fig.: le tenebre ci avvolgevano da ogni parte; si sentiva avvolto da una calda ondata di simpatia. 2. rifl. a.Girare, volgersi attorno, arrotolarsi: la fune s’avvolge alla campana dell’argano; Come sul capo al naufrago L’onda s’avvolve e pesa(Manzoni). b. Circondarsi, avvilupparsi: s’avvolse in un ampio mantello; Carlo Magno s’avvolgea tremando Nel lenzuol d’Aquisgrana(Carducci). c. ant. Aggirarsi per un luogo: Pel bosco Ferraù molto s’avvolse (Ariosto). ◆ Part. pres.avvolgènte, per lo più con valore verbale, usato soprattutto nel linguaggio milit.: manovra avvolgente, effettuata allo scopo di aggirare e circondare il nemico; con altro senso,suono avvolgente, il suono riprodotto da apparecchi ad alta fedeltà, quando si diffonde in modo uniforme e con timbro morbido. ◆ Part. pass.avvòlto, anche come agg.: essere,presentarsi avvolto in un mantello, in un lenzuolo; e fig.: casa avvolta nel silenzio; faccenda avvolta nel mistero;origini avvolte nella leggenda; la brezza atlantica cessò, dall’oceano arrivò una spessa cortina di nebbia e la città si trovò avvolta in un sudario di calura (Antonio Tabucchi).

[link](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/avvolgere/)

Comment: Scusa, non riesco a seguire compiutamente il tuo ragionamento. Il dizionario dice una cosa, e quindi tu ne deduci tutt'altra? Anzi, quattro diverse fra loro (riempito, annebbiato, concentrato, avvolto)? Hai un'idea di come faccia “tornito” ad assumere questi altri significati?

Comment: Spesso in poesia o nei romanzi si usano delle parole che non hanno il significato letterale. In questo attornito significa "Sembrava avvolto dalla sua voce" nel senso che sentiva solo la sua voce. Non so se riesci a capire ciò che intendo.

Comment: Grazie per avermi dato del lento di comprendonio, ma quello che non capisco è se te l'ha rivelato la Ferrante di persona, se è solo una tua ipotesi o altro. (E che parola è “attornito”?)

Comment: @DaG Non mi sembra di averti offeso in alcun modo.Comunque, È una mia ipotesi e quando lessi questo romanzo in classe l'avevo interpretato così.

Comment: Forse sei giovane, e allora permettimi di spiegarti – visto che stiamo parlando di parole e modi di dire italiani – che “non so se riesci a capire” non è una delle tre cose più diplomatiche che si possano dire a un interlocutore.

Comment: Capito. Comunque, grazie del -1.

Comment: Il -1 è semplicemente perché dissento da questa ipotesi e non vedo un ragionamento a suo sostegno. Nello spirito dei siti SE, il -1 significa che non si ritiene utile la risposta in questione.

Comment: Capisco. A me sembra giusto, in quanto io credo che a volte un romanzo o poesia può essere interpretato in vari modi diversi.

Comment: Questo è giusto e sacrosanto, ma non significa che qualunque interpretazione “a orecchio” vada bene, in assenza di qualche base linguistica, etimologica, filologica o altro. Altrimenti, tu dici che significa “avvolto”, io dico che significa “plasmato”, un altro dice che significa “disgustato” o “ingannato” o “salvato”, e allora? Abbiamo tutti ragione? Nessuno? È un gioco?

Comment: @DaG Beh, Io ho provato a dare la spiegazione più plausibile.